# How to display decimal data type with two decimal place in .Net Core rest API response

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core, rest

I am working on a REST API project in .net core 3.1 (C#). My Model is as below.

```
 public class Transaction {
        [SwaggerSchema("Item code.")]
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }

        /// <example>1</example>
        [SwaggerSchema("Transaction type.")]
        public int TransactionType { get; set; }
        
        /// <example>50</example>
        [SwaggerSchema("Transaction amount.")]
        [Required]       
        [Range(0,int.MaxValue,ErrorMessage ="Amount must be greater than zero.")]  
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        /// <example>ABC45345</example>
        [SwaggerSchema("Comment related to the transaction.")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

I am using this model Transaction object as parameter to my Post method. the issue is, when user provide amount as .9 ,it fails and thro error.

Also values stored in databases like 2.00, 150.00 are displays without decimal places in GET calls. My customer want to see all amount with two decimal place. Can someone advise if any other way we can handle this decimal datatype to accept .77 (without leading zero) and show two decimal point regardless of if the value has decimal place or not?

we can manage this with string data type but i don't want to change the data type from decimal. Please advise.

Comment: Did you try to add the annotation _[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "0.0")]_?

Comment: Yes, @Steve. I tried it already and there is no effect in the output.

Comment: Api provides a json response. Whoever consumes the json should display it in whatever format they want in the UI side. formatting is not api's job.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any way to handle this without changing the data type. I changed my code as below

```
private string _amount;
[SwaggerSchema("Transaction amount.")]
    [Required]
    public string Amount
    {
        get => _amount;
        set => _amount = decimal.Parse(value, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,
            new CultureInfo("en-US")).ToString("F2");
    }
```